# Definition of essentially T-invariant function

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

A function is $T$-invariant if $f(T(x))=f(x)$ for all $x\in X$. In text book: Introduction to Dynamical system by Brin, it defines *essentially $T$-invariant*: if $f(T(x))=f(x)$ almost every for $x\in X$, i.e. $\mu(\{x\in X: f(T(x))\neq f(x)\}=0$.

If $f$ is $T$-invariant, then $f(T^n(x))=f(T^{n-1}(x))=\dots=f(x)$. I think this property still holds when $f$ is essentially $T$-invariant.

Here is my proof: Note that
\begin{align*}
\{x\in X:f(T(x))\neq f(x)\}\supset& \{x\in T(X): f(T(x))\neq f(x)\}\\
=& \{x=Ty: f(T^2(y))\neq f(T(y)), y\in X\}.
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
&\mu(\{y\in X: f(T^2(y))\neq f(T(y)\}\\
=&\mu(\{x=Ty: f(T^2(y))\neq f(T(y)), y\in X\})\\
\leq & \mu(\{x\in X:f(T(x))\neq f(x)\})=0.
\end{align*}
This means that $fT^2=fT$ a.e. If $\mathcal{A}$ is complete then the a.e. property is transitive, so that $fT^2=fT=f$ a.e. Then by induction, one can show that $fT^n=fT^{n-1}=\dots=f$ a.e.

Is the proof right? And does the property still hold?

Comment: I think my proof is wrong, see comments in the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\circ T=f$ a.e. and $f\circ T=f\circ T^{2}$ a.e. then  $f=f\circ T^{2}$ a.e. This does not require completeness of $\mathcal A$: $\{x: (f\circ T)(x)\neq f(x)\}$  and $\{x: (f\circ T^{2})(x)\neq (f\circ T)(x)\}$ are null sets and so their union is a null set.

Also, note that $0=\mu \{x: f(T(x)) \neq f(x)\}=\mu (T^{-1}( \{x: f(T(x)) \neq f(x)\})=\mu \{y: f(T^{2}y) \neq f(Ty)\}$.

Comment: By assumption of completeness come from this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752416/equivalence-relation-almost-everywhere. It says that $\{x:fT^2(x)\neq f(x)\}$ might not in the sigma algebra.

Comment: $f=g$ a.e. does not require measurability of $\{x: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$. By definition $f=g$ a.e. if $\{x: f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is contained in a set in $\mathcal A$ with measure $0$. @evenzhou

Comment: I see, the definition you used is less restricted, just like what the first comment in that link says.

Comment: I find my proof might be wrong here: $\mu(\{y\in X: f(T^2(y))\neq f(T(y)\}\}=\mu(\{x=Ty: f(T^2(y))\neq f(T(y)), y\in X\})$. I write this because there is a bijection. BUT bijection can't preserves measure, as $[0,1]\equiv [0,2]$ but there are not equal in measure.

Comment: @evenzhou I have edited my answer.

Comment: You use the assumption that $T$ is measure-preserving, right?

Comment: Yes, that is it. @evenzhou